# Availability of docstring from my own functions across different scripts in Spyder editor

Tags: python, python-3.x, spyder, documentation, docstring

I'm coding in Spyder 5.0.5 for Python 3.8 and I tend to document my code.
If I write docstring for a function in a certain script, then, every time I use that function in that very same script, if I place the mouse in the function's name, I get a pop-up displaying all the info from the docstring. Same as it would happen with any function imported from any previously installed package.
However, if I import that very same function (the one I wrotte) into another script and place the mouse where I'm calling it, all I get is a pop-up displaying "No documentation available".
How can I make docstring from my own functions available across different scripts?

Comment: How is your directory structure when doing the import?

Comment: @DanielAlthviz All my scripts, including the one where the function is defined and the one where I'm calling it, are in the same directory in my HD, which is Python'd working directory.

Comment: After testing in an environment with Spyder 5.0.5 I'm able to reproduce this (the no documentation available message appears to me). However if I use the latest Spyder version (5.1.5) is working. The problem there is that to have the latest Spyder version you will need to use the `conda-forge` channel, pip or [use the standalone installer](https://www.spyder-ide.org/#section-download) (available for Windows or MacOS). In case you use conda, I would suggest for you to create an environment using the conda-forge channel (to not merge channels in case you are running spyder from the base env).